# getting error when using pipes and ngModel in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I got a custom dropdown where `value` from selected dropdown will bind in `input` value in my reactive form using `ngModel`, also I had applied mask in my `input` fields using pipe, here is all relevant code :

**html file**

```
<form [formGroup]="creditCardForm" (ngSubmit)="submitCreditCardForm()">
  <input 
     [ngModel]="selectedCard.cardNumberMasked | creditCardMask: true"
     (ngModelChange)="selectedCard.cardNumberMasked = $event"
     type="text"
     formControlName="creditCardNumber">
</form>
```

**ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  creditCardForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private builder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.creditCardForm = builder.group({
      creditCardNumber: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }    
}
```

**mask.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'creditCardMask',
})
export class CreditCardMaskPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, showMask: boolean): string {
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
      value = JSON.stringify(value);
    }

    if (!showMask || (value.length < 16 && value.length < 15)) {
      return value;
    }

    return `${value.substr(0, 4)} ${'\u2022'.repeat(4)} ${'\u2022'.repeat(
      4
    )} ${value.substr(value.length - 4, value.length)}`;
  }
}
```

I know using `ngModel` in reactive form is deprecated but I need to use it for binding value from selected dropdown, this is the error I get in my console:

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined: 512345444444444'. Current value: 'undefined: 5123 •••• •••• 4444'.

**error**
[image]

any suggestion on how to solve this or any better practice ? thanks

Comment: use [value] and (valueChange) instead

Comment: replace ngModel @D?

Comment: it work for error but `formControlName` dont get the value of `creditCardNumber` @D

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use **ngModel** along side **formControlName**, for using pipe you can try using `[value]` and then assign formControl value to it to update value every time you insert new value to input:

```
<form [formGroup]="creditCardForm" (ngSubmit)="submitCreditCardForm()">
  <input 
     [value]="creditCardForm.get('creditCardNumber').value | creditCardMask: true"
     type="text"
     formControlName="creditCardNumber">
</form>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-wspwp3)

Comment: but i need to binding selected dropdown value, that why im using ngModel

Comment: First you didn't mention in you question but It's OK simply you can use dropdown with formControl and use select instead of input.